# logarithmic integral function and asymptotic expansion

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Show that Logarithmic integral function $$\int_2^x {1\over \log(t)} \, dt = Li(x)$$  has asymptotic expansion of the form $${x\over \log(x)}\cdot\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j\cdot (\log(x))^{-j}.$$

I tried different stuff but I did not conclude to solve it. Any help for solving this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please include some of the things you have tried so that we can see where you are stuck.

Comment: $\int_2^x {dt\over log(t)} = \text{li}(x)-\text{li}(2)$, I presume

Comment: Hint: Use the asymptotic expansion of the exponential integral

Comment: [Disclaimer: I am a student, not a professional mathematician.] You can get it directly by repeated partial integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very sketchy answer!

Observe, that

$$\text{Li(x)}=-\int_{\log(2)}^{\log(x)}\frac{e^{-y}}{y}=\text{Ei}(\log(x))-\text{Ei}(\log(2))$$

where $\text{Ei(x)}=\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-q}}{q}$   the Expontential integral .

Doing intgration by parts N times we obtain 
$$
\text{Ei(x)}=\frac{e^{-x}}{x}-\frac{e^{-x}}{x^2}+\frac{2!e^{-x}}{x^3}+....+(-1)^{N-1}\frac{e^{-x}(N-1)!}{x^n}+R(N)
$$
where $R(N)$ is the remaining integral.

We conclude that
$$
\text{Ei(x)}=\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{k!}{x^k}
$$

in an asymptotic sense. 
Now plug in $\log(x)$ and $\log(2)$ and you are done.